# Nested regex in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe, nlp

I am working on the cosmetic ingredient data and trying to solve a regex problem where I want to replace "," with "-".
For example,

```py
x = ['6,7- dihydro-1,1,2,3,3-pentamethyl-4(5h)-indanone',
'steareth-10, polyacrylamide c1,14 isoparaffin, laureth-7, propylene glycol, hydrolyzed soy protein, aloe barbadensis, 1,2-hexanediol']
```

Here, I only wish to substitute `,` between the chemical formula to be replaced with `-` and not the word separator.

For example, expected outout like

```
6-7- dihydro-1-1-2-3-3-pentamethyl-4(5h)-indanone
steareth-10, polyacrylamide c1-14 isoparaffin, laureth-7, propylene glycol, hydrolyzed soy protein, aloe barbadensis, 1-2-hexanediol
```

I have tried creating generic regex and even though I am able to match the data, I am unable to replace.

```
x.str.contains(r'(\d,\d,\d,\d,\d,\d,\d,\d,\d,\d)|(\d,\d,\d,\d,\d,\d,\d,\d)|(\d,\d,\d,\d,\d,\d,\d)|(\d,\d,\d,\d,\d,\d)|(\d,\d,\d,\d,\d)|(\d,\d,\d,\d)|(\d,\d,\d)|(\d,\d)')
```

or `x.str.findall(r"([, 0-9]+)-")`

Please help with the approach

Comment: Perhaps like this? `(\d),(?=\d)`  https://regex101.com/r/9vk3pB/1

Comment: I used a similar regex but it breaks when used on multiple numbers and commas for example - 6,7- dihydro-1,1,2,3,3-pentamethyl-4(5h)-indanone, here it'll work on 6,7 but not on 1,1,2,3,3

Comment: I have four questions about this: (1) Are the word-separating commas guaranteed to be followed by whitespace? Are the number-separating commas guaranteed to not be followed by whitespace? (3) Are the number-separating commas guaranteed to be following by a digit? (4) Do you absolutely want a regexp or are you open to other solutions as well?

Comment: Hi Stef, (4) I'm open to other solutions. Regarding (1),(2),(3) - word separating commas need not to have guaranteed whitespace. With  numbers, the possible test cases are the example present in the example above

Answer (score 1):

You could use a capture group:

```
(\d),(?=[\d,]*-)
```

**Explanation**

- `(\d)` Capture group 1, match a single digit
- `,` Match literally (to be replaced)
- `(?=[\d,]*-)` Positive lookahead, assert optional digits or comma's to the right followed by a hyphen

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q0B5Z9/1).

In the replacement use the first capture group followed by a hyphen `\1-`

Example

```
import re

x = ['6,7- dihydro-1,1,2,3,3-pentamethyl-4(5h)-indanone',
     'steareth-10, polyacrylamide c1,14 isoparaffin, laureth-7, propylene glycol, hydrolyzed soy protein, aloe barbadensis, 1,2-hexanediol',
     '1,1,2,3,3'
     ]

for s in x:
    print(re.sub(r'(\d),(?=[\d,]*-)', r'\1-', s))
```

Output

```
6-7- dihydro-1-1-2-3-3-pentamethyl-4(5h)-indanone
steareth-10, polyacrylamide c1,14 isoparaffin, laureth-7, propylene glycol, hydrolyzed soy protein, aloe barbadensis, 1-2-hexanediol
1,1,2,3,3
```

---

An example using a positive lookbehind and a match only, where you would just use a `-` in the replacement:

```
(?<=\d),(?=[\d,]*-)
```

And in the code:

```
re.sub(r'(?<=\d),(?=[\d,]*-)', r'-', s)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c8p8eJ/1)